# Displaying fields with values only with foreach limit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have db structure

id | ref_id | amenity1 | amenity2 | amenity3 | amenity4 | amenity5

Each amenity column has values 1 or 0.
When a search is made, I need to display the field that has values not equals to zero (value != 0).
I know I can do this in VIEW as

```
if($data->amenity1 == 0) echo '';
```

But I need it to be automated with limit.

My code for MODEL is

```
function select_all_active_amenities($for_id){
    foreach($for_id as $id){
        $prop_id = $id->vbc_item_id;
    }
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('vbc_property_amenities');
    $this->db->where_in(array('v_ref_id'=> $prop_id));
    $this->db->limit(5);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    return $result;
}
```

Please help

Comment: is there fixed 6 amenity columns only or it changing dynamically ?

Comment: @jothi, there are about 105 of them but may have to increase in future..

Comment: why you not prefer this one  if($amenity1 == 0) echo '';   ? what is the problem ?

Comment: okay. because on search page in filters I have fixed numbers set to show 5 amenities (which can be expanded). if I do ` if($data->amenity1 == 0) echo '';` then I wont be able to maintain 5 amenities as I dont want to show those amenities there which doesnt have any value

Comment: is there any extra column name except  these two kind id | amenity1 2 3.. ?

Comment: yes there are but they won't bother as they do not have values 0 or one.. That's why I preferred something like where != 0

Comment: no no im asking  is there any other column in table except id and amenity... and anything other column there  ?

Comment: Yes, ref_id is ther.

Comment: can you show your table structure  ?

Comment: updated in question now..

Comment: okay if amenity1=0  and  amenity2=1  in this case you want show the column row or not ?

Comment: if amenity1=0 (it will not be displayed) and if amenity2=1 (will be displayed). The idea is all with 1 will display except for those has value 0.

Comment: you dont need to fetch  the colum where amenity1,2,3,4=0 is it ?

Comment: you are right.. I will brief.. search was made for hotels in Delhi. if there where 50 hotels found then I need amenities for those hotels only which would have value 1. Any amenity which is not there in any of those 50 hotels (value = 0) will not be displayed. that is my problem.

Comment: can you tell me exact column name except those dynamic columns amenity1,2,3,4..

Comment: you mean I will have to execute that query using all amenity column names?

Comment: Please stop tag-spamming every CI question with [tag:codeigniter-2] and [tag:codeigniter-3]... it can't be both.  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just remove empty column using custom array build

```
function select_all_active_amenities($for_id){
foreach($for_id as $id){
    $prop_id = $id->vbc_item_id;
}
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->distinct('v_ref_id');
$this->db->from('vbc_property_amenities');
$this->db->where_in(array('v_ref_id'=> $prop_id));
// $this->db->limit(5);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 $result1 = $query->result_array();

 //fetch the value as array 

//and this query for fetch the column name what you have right now an where not equal to id and ref_id

 $this->db->query("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='vbc_property_amenities' AND COLUMN_NAME !='id' AND COLUMN_NAME != 'ref_id AND COLUMN_NAME !='id' ")->result_array();
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result2 = $query->result_array();

foreach($result as $key1=>$row1)
{

        foreach($result2 as $key2=>$row2)
        {

            if($row2 ==$row1[$row2] && $row1 ==0)
            {

                unset($result[$key1][$row2]);
            }

        }



}

//$result only have the where value=1 

return $result;

//you just limit the five in your view page 
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Any idea how do I restrict duplicate display of amenities.. for eg.. if hotel1 has amenity1 and hotel2 also has amenity1, then amenity1 is displaying twice.

Comment: above code did you understand what i did is it useful to you ?

Comment: I actually got that working already.. Now my challenge is duplicates.. right now I have only 2 properties in db with same amenities.. And when I run my query, it echo v_aircondition
v_queenbed,
v_kingbed,
v_aircondition,
v_queenbed,
v_kingbed,

Comment: now you build new array and there use in_array function to get if already have value like this in new array not insert it into new array  http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_in_array

Answer (score 1):

Add the "DISTINCT" keyword to a query before Select ,to get unique records

```
$this->db->distinct();
```

Hope it may help you out!

Comment: bro,You can also try group_by @Sebastian

Comment: right now I have only 2 properties in db with same amenities.. And when I run my query, it echo v_aircondition v_queenbed, v_kingbed, v_aircondition, v_queenbed, v_kingbed... See the duplicates?  How can I possibly achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried "$this->db->group_by('column_name');"  ??